# Can I have multiple database in indexeddb using jsstore

Tags: angular, typescript, indexeddb

can i have multiple databases in indexeddb using jsstore in angular2.

please guide me how can we achieve this. please provide syntax for that.

will this degrade the performance?

below is my service code

```
constructor(private _http:Http)
{
    this._connection=new JsStore.Instance();
    let that=this, dbName='DTSubscription';
    JsStore.isDbExist(dbName,function(isExist)
    {
        if(isExist)
        {
            that._connection.openDb(dbName);
        }
        else
        {
            const Database=that.GetDatabase();
            that._connection.createDb(Database);
        }
    },function(err)
    {
        alert(err.Message);
    });

    this._connection=new JsStore.Instance();
    let t=this, db2='DTSubscriptionNew';
    JsStore.isDbExist(db2,function(isExist)
    {
        if(isExist)
        {
            t._connection.openDb(db2);
        }
        else{
            const Database2=t.GetDatabase2();
            t._connection.createDb(Database2);
        }
    },function(err)
    {
    alert(err.Message);
    });
}
```

The db has been created. But while inserting I need to mention db otherwise it gives error like this -

{
  Name: "table_not_exist", 
  Message: "Table 'ArticleNew' does not exist"
}

I can see db is there.

Comment: What have you tried so far, aside from the tutorial you have linked? And regarding the tutorial, what were your problems. Show us your work, please.

Comment: can you pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple database but only one will work at a time. So if you want to use two database in a app - change the database by calling 'openDb' api.

So if your database is - DTSubscription, DTSubscriptionNew

When you want to execute query for the db - DTSubscription. The query will be like this -

```
var Connection = new JsStore.Instance();
Connection.openDb('DTSubscription');
```

When you want to execute query for db - 'DTSubscriptionNew'

```
Connection.openDb('DTSubscriptionNew');
```

Since you are using angular2, i will recommended to define two service for two database and keep the JsStore connection common. This way the particular service will execute the query for particular database.

For more info about how to use this, take a look at demo projects for using two db in jsstore -

https://github.com/ujjwalguptaofficial/multipledb-in-jsstore

## Update

Starting from JsStore v4 , you can use multiple connection for multiple database and all will work parallely.

Comment: Thanks.I have created connection object as per your suggestion.but,I am getting {Name: "db_not_exist", Message: "Database 'DTSubscription' does not exist"} error

Comment: yeah it means db has not been created. The above code will work only if db has been created if you are not sure  about db creation then you should use the method of 'JsStore.isExist' to get the db connection . Let me update my answer.

Comment: I think for your situation - first create db on page load and grab the connection everytime you need to execute the query using var con= new JsStore.Instance('db_name').

Comment: I am using above code in constructor.Then I am using var con= new JsStore.Instance('db_name')  ,before executing the query.but I am getting same error.

Comment: If you are getting db_not_exist error that means db has not been created, debug your code to see that db is being created or not. I will write article explaining how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi,my db get created before writing this line var Connection = new JsStore.Instance('DTSubscription');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159738/discussion-between-ujjwal-kumar-gupta-and-kamalav).